# Hot reloading of VideoJS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, video.js, react-hot-loader

I am having a video js component in my react project. I am also using marker plugin on video.js. Every component in my project gets Hot Reloaded whenever I make any change in them, but my videoJS component doesn't get hot reloaded. For example: If I make any change in markers then it doesn't get reflected on webpage as hot reloaded. I have to refresh webpage everytime I make any change in videoJS. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Videojs is base on jQuery, it's not a React component.
You could have a try with:
https://github.com/video-react/video-react

Comment: video-react is not actually using video.js, But its heavily inspired by video.js. So, you will get the power of plugins in video.js, if you use this component.